# Next monthly clean-up day - answerathon!

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, events

On October 31st, we had an event in the chat room and cleaned up all the unanswered questions at the time.

On November 30th, we fixed a bunch of tags, added descriptions and wiki excerpts.

This month, what suits people better for an event - December 30th (I assume people are busy New Year's eve), or before Christmas - like the 22ndish?

Also, any preferences for theme of the event - clear out the unanswered questions seemed to be the preference in the chatroom earlier today, as the number is creeping up again.

I'll be willing to put some bounties on questions for the event too, to make it more enticing ;)

---

OK I'm settling on another answerathon - not only to clear up unanswered ones, but also to answer some with only 1 answer on them.  What time (UTC) suits everyone the most, on say, the 28/29th, or 23rd?

Comment: 08:00 until 24:00 would be great for me!

Answer (score 5):

I would prefer something after the 26th but before the 30th. While some people are offline, those who are at work are probably able to sneak a little time for personal things, and those who are at home are probably relaxing and can get online if need be. Right up till the 24th ticks over to the 25th I'm super busy with work that needs to get done while people are still around, holiday parties to attend, shopping and wrapping etc. By the 28th I could do with a little excitement.

Answer (score 3):

I think an answerathon would be a good choice, and if you're willing to put some bounties on it, we have a nice Christmas present ;)

I personally would prefer something around the 22. Between Christmas and New Year's Eve a lot of people are not online.